# Auto Populating From Sheets Into another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have one google spreadsheet that syncs responses from two google forms. There are three sheets in this spreadsheet: form responses 1, form responses 2 and data. I want to sync the data from form responses 1 to to the relevant columns in data as soon as new responses appear in it. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

To illustrate, what I want to do here is take any new data from the "date" "activity" and "notes" and append it to the same name columns in the "raw data" sheet.

Comment: Use `IMPORTRANGE()` function. If need to import specific columns then use `QUERY()` with `IMPORTRANGE()` function.

Comment: Just to confirm, you would want to sync data ONLY from "Form Responses 1" sheet to your "Raw Data" sheet, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

try in Raw Data sheet in the Date column:

```
=FILTER('Form Responses 2'!B2:B; 'Form Responses 2'!B2:B<>"")
```